# why datetime is not localized in asp.net webmethod?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, localization, webmethod

i've something like that

```
[WebMethod]
public static string web_method()
{
    return getDate();
}

public static string getDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
}
```

the getDate method is call with page_load() and if the culture Arabic it returns the month name and day name translated, if it's called with the web_method the date is not translated.

help plz, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
  // Creates a CultureInfo for Jordan.
  CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-JO");

  // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
  // and the CultureInfo.

  return DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy", ci);
```

Might help